# Typo3 FAL Extension Backend Upload

Tags: upload, typo3, backend, fal

I have an Extension which holds a list of PDF-Docs.
In my TCA I defined the uploadfolder, but after uploading a file, it goes to "fileadmin/user_upload". Not to my defined folder "fileadmin/user_upload/my_folder"

My TCA

```
'pdfs' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:xxx/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:xxx_domain_model_pdflist.pdfs',
        'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(                'pdfs',
            array(
                'maxitems' => 200,
                'max_size' => 5000,
                'uploadfolder' => 'fileadmin/user_upload/bffpdf',
                'show_thumbs' => 1,
                'size' => 20,
                'minitems' => 0,
            ),
            'pdf'
        ),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    ),
```

The Folder exists and is shown up in the Fileadmin.

I do not want to override the userdefault uploadfolder.

Greetz
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Am not familiar with typo3, but my following code works perfect for me, I think this may help you.

My TCA

```
'image' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:titech_catalog/locallang_db.xml:tx_titechcatalog_category.image',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'group',
            'internal_type' => 'file',
            'allowed' => $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext'],
            'max_size' => $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['maxFileSize'],
            'uploadfolder' => 'uploads/tx_titechcareers',
            'show_thumbs' => 1,
            'size' => 1,
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 10,
        )
    )
```

Code to create this path is in 'ext_emconf.php' file,

```
'createDirs' => 'uploads/tx_titechcareers/rte/',
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with FAL.